# Дебаггинг unity3d на вк

Tags: unity3d, отладка, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Столкнулся с проблемами тестирования и отладки unity3d игры в среде социальной сети. Возникло три вопроса:

1. Как прицепится к процессу в встроенного в хром unity плеера через mono develop?
2. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при запуске в Unity3d Build And Run открывалась не сгенерированная страничка, а ссылка на приложение, как это сделано например в Flash Builder?
3. Возможно ли вообще прицепится к процессу не плеера в хроме?

Answer (score 1):

1. По-моему нельзя, по крайней мере никогда не видел такого.
2. А билд тоже сразу сам должен лечь куда надо? Тоже не видел такой возможности.

Игровую механику мы тестим в Юнити едиторе, и если надо мультиплеер то ещё билдим на винду, ставя заглушки на вк апи и тд.
Взаимодействие же страницы и веб билда смотрим по логам от js-страницы, и от ответов от бэкенда.